# Insert into multiple tables using stream & tasks

Tags: snowflake-task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As per the official documentation, it depicts as though we can insert into multiple tables from a task. Which sounds inaccurate since

- Once consumed the offsets of the stream are reset
- It is possible to execute only one SQL statement from a task

am I missing something here? I want to be able to insert into 2 tables reading out of a stream through the task.

[image: multiple tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a multi-table insert:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.  Multi-table inserts are one way, but there is another.

The pointer in the stream is only advanced at the end of a transactions.  Therefore, you can enclose multiple DML statements that read from the stream in a single transaction. Unfortunately, tasks can only execute a single SQL statements, so you will have to embed your queries in a stored procedure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was my next move, but fortunately the accepted answer proved enough in my case